# Pandas count unique value and change to percentage and put into the plotly bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, data-visualization, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
Country  
 Japan   
 Japan   
 Korea   
 India   
 India   
  USA    
  USA    
  USA
```

I need to count the unique values of the country column and change to percentage and need to put in the x-axis and y-axis of plotly bar chart. Can anyone teach me how to do it?

Comment: Have you done any research?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df.Country.value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Comment: and `.mul(100)` would help :) +1

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I want to ask how to add a header for the percentage column after use the value_counts

Comment: @Jason Do you mean the column name? That's a different question entirely.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Yes. I want to ask after I use the value_counts get the unique value. How can I use the unique value column? Most of the way I found is call the column name. Should I post this question in a new post?

Comment: @Jason Look at the docs, `value_counts()` returns a Series in this case. What you do with the Series afterwards is entirely up to you! :)